# how to draw recursive picture with tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, recursion

Suppose I need to draw a Kantor set, or a Sierpinski carpet, or a Koch curve, or any such of simple fractal.

Tipically you can do that by drawing a picture, then rescalining it and replicating in several places.

I tried by using `\foreach \a in {...}` combined to `\begin{scope}[shift{some function of \a},scale{some function of \a}]`

but I did not succeed.

So which is the correct way to combine a cycle for with moving and rescaling a picture?

---

More precisely I tried:

```
\foreach \a in {0,1,2}

\begin{scope}[shift={(10\a,0)}, scale=1/3]
  mypicture

\end{scope}
```

this gives errors

> "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup."

and with group parenthesis

```
\foreach \a in {0,1,2}

{\begin{scope}[shift={(10\a,0)}, scale=1/3]
  mypicture

\end{scope}}
```

which seems just not working.

Comment: Maybe http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/nontech/fractals/

Comment: Did you mean `10*\a`?

Comment: Does these help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342082/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386968/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112912/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380096/1952

Comment: Ok, thanks for 10*\a (!) but still does not work

Comment: Nice @Ignasi, that's very powerfull! However, I would like to know how I could let work "foreach" and "scope" together

Comment: Ok, with 10*\a and group parenthesis it seems to work!

Comment: @HenriMenke would you write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in you code.

1. You probably want to multiply `\a` by 10, so you have to write `10*\a`.
2. The body of the foreach loop has to be in a brace group if it is more than a single statement.  While

   ```
   \foreach \a in {0,1,2}
     \node at (10*\a,0) {\a};
   ```

   is okay (single statement, ending with `;`), this is not

   ```
   \foreach \a in {0,1,2}
     \begin{scope}[shift={(10*\a,0)}]
       \node at (0,0) {\a}; % scanning actually stops at this ;
     \end{scope} % this is not reached -> error!
   ```

If you correct these errors, the following MWE typesets just fine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {0,1,2} {
    \begin{scope}[shift={(10*\a,0)}]
      \node at (0,0) {\a};
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```